# React Native canOpenUrl - The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)

Tags: ios, react-native, mailto

I'm working a React Native (0.64.0) app in iOS and am trying to open a link. I'm running this app using Xcode 14 on the built-in iPhone 12 simulator. I have a `onPressSendEmail` function that calls another function called `OpenURLButton` like this:

```
  const OpenURLButton = (url) => {
    const handlePress = async () => {
      // Checking if the link is supported for links with custom URL scheme.
      const supported = await Linking.canOpenURL(url);
  
      if (supported) {
        // Opening the link with some app, if the URL scheme is "http" the web link should be opened
        // by some browser in the mobile
        await Linking.openURL(url);
      } else {
        Alert.alert(`Don't know how to open this URL: ${url}`);
      }
    };
    handlePress();
  }

  onPressSendEmail = () => {
    OpenURLButton(`mailto:?to=`);
  }
```

It should just open their mail app like how `mailto` functions on web.

I edited my `Info.plist` like this to accept mailto protocol:

```
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>mailto</string>
        <string>tel</string>
        <string>telprompt</string>
    </array>
```

But I still get this error coming from `canOpenURL`: "-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "mailto:?to=" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)""

Similar questions on StackOverflow were usually about plugins or other apps and not "mailto". I've read that simulators can have trouble opening email links but I wanted to be certain something else wasn't wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using the iPhone simulator from Xcode.

**mailto: links will not work in the simulator.**